# What does the line " KEY `idx_pid` (`person_id`), " mean?

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and am working on an online server (MYSQL version 5.1.69) and i have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE `person_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `info_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `info` text NOT NULL,
  `note` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_pid` (`person_id`),
  KEY `person_info_info_type_id_exists` (`info_type_id`)
)
```

Can someone explain to me what " KEY `idx_pid` (`person_id`)," does?

Comment: So if there are multiple tables each creating KEY 'idx_pid' ('person_id') does this mean that idx_pid acts as a sort of forgein key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`KEY`, in MySQL, is an alias for `INDEX`; you can see this in the pseudo grammar in the [`CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) documentation:

```
[INDEX|KEY] [index_name] (index_col_name,...)
```

It represents the definition of an index on a table, and nothing more. Here,

```
KEY `idx_pid` (`person_id`),
```

…creates an index named "idx_pid" on the column "person_id". This could have also been written as,

```
INDEX `idx_pid` (`person_id`),
```

However, MySQL's `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command (and other commands) will prefer `KEY`. It is an unfortunate choice for a keyword here, as it has nothing to do with a “key¹” in the relational databases sense of the word.

¹A key, in relational database theory, is a set of columns that uniquely identify a row.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're creating an index named "idx_pid" on the person_info.person_id column.

Answer (score 0):

This adds an index named `idx_pid` on the `person_id` column which speeds up queries using the `persond_id` as condition.

You can read up on [MySQL indexes here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).